# How to group items in array?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have an array of items(day in month numbers), now I want to group them by month, so I want to turn this:

```
(1, True), ... (31, True), (1, False) ...(28, True),...
```

Into this:

```
[(1, True), ... (31, True)], [(1, False) ...(28, True)],...
```

I am using python 3. How should I do it?

Comment: How are you identifying the month? or is it assumed that the list has every day of a (non-leap) year?

Comment: The month is all items between to items with value 1 including first value with value 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generator function that yields a new group each time the first value goes down rather than up:

```
def group_by_month(items):
    month = []
    for day, flag in items:
        if month and month[-1][0] > day:
            # new month starting
            yield month
            month = []
        month.append((day, flag))
    if month:
        yield month
```

You can either iterate over the generated months or gather all months in one big list with:

```
grouped = list(group_by_month(items))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
days = [(1, True), (2, False), (31, True), (1, False), (2, True)]
month = []
grouped_by_month = []
last = (0, False)

for pair in days:
    if pair < last:
        grouped_by_month.append(month)
        month = []
    month.append(pair)
    last = pair
grouped_by_month.append(month)

print(grouped_by_month)
```

Giving:

```
[[(1, True), (2, False), (31, True)], [(1, False), (2, True)]]
```